# Laravel 9 - why adding ['middleware' => 'auth'] to route::group causes "require(auth): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory" error

Tags: laravel

I'm new to php and Laravel.  I'm using Laravel 9 with Fortify and some custom login ui.  They are working correctly.  The home page nav bar is showing the Login and Register links if user is not authenticated.  The Login and Register links are working fine as well.  What I'm trying to do now is to auto route user to the Login page if the user is not authenticated.  So below is what I did.

In my web.php, I've this line to route all admin path to routes\admin\adminRoutes.php.

```
Route::prefix('/admin')->group(__DIR__ . '\admin\adminRoutes.php');
```

In the routes\admin\adminRoutes.php, I have this:

```
Route::name('admin.')->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

    Route::get('/home', function () {
        return redirect()->route('home');
});
```

});

Basically, I added the ['middleware' => 'auth'] to the group function.  But for some reason, this cause the site to failed with this error that I don't understand:

```
require(auth): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

What is that means and what did I do wrong?

Comment: Try doing `Route::name('admin.')->middleware('auth')->group(function () { })` , or `Route::name('admin.')->group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () { })` instead.

Comment: Thanks IGP.  Route::name('admin.')->middleware('auth')->group(function () { }) work.   The latter gives me "Array to string conversion" error.

Comment: What about middleware(['auth']) ?

Comment: Sorry, not understanding.  Route::name('admin.')->middleware('auth')->group(function () { }) works.